# Physical shapes you can't simulate using mathematical functions

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

*This question borders philosophy, so I would be happy to move it somewhere else if this forum is inappropriate.*

While doing some 3D function plotting, it occurred to me that I can plot any shape that I can think of (theoretically that is), including all observable plain objects. My question is: **Is there any physical object the look of which one cannot plot as a mathematical function?** Note that the difficulty of such a task is beside the point; I am merely concerned with the decidability of this issue.

Comment: Show me a sphere as plot of some **function**.

Comment: @tom Cheater ;-)

Comment: No. The other way around is problematic though.

Comment: @tom: $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3:(u,v)\mapsto (\cos u \cos v, \cos u \sin v, \sin u)$. The sphere is given by the set of image points of the function.

Comment: A sphere is *locally* the graph of a function.

Comment: If you understand plotting in this context as assignment of a value to each point in space, then defining the object itself equals definition of the function! For instance, a solid ball is an indicator function that is $1$ if $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$, $0$ otherwise. In this formal context, the function *is* the object. A description of a definable object that you can specify at all, is a function already.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Or better, the sphere is the image of $id:S_2\to S_2$ where $S_2$ is the sphere :)

Comment: Why are you all thinking of explicitly specified surfaces? That's a really narrow definition of a function! What about isosurfaces (level sets), density plots and so on? Isn't $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ a function?

Comment: Sure, but I think the point is that as long as you're being flexible about how you define your object in terms of a function, there's no limit on the shapes you can desribe in those terms. The question is: is it interesting?

Comment: Of course you can plot anything as isosurface of some function e.g. $\chi_{\text{anything}}$. But I would understand plot of **function** as set $\{ (x,f(x)) \}$

Comment: Exactly @orion. So I guess everything in the physical universe is a mathematical function of some kind. Are there any some resources where questions like this were contemplated?

Comment: I think a good example where the power of implicit function is evident, is the povray raytracer. You can create almost anything just by combining functions. I've had some experience with that, and once you learn a few trick of how to combine elements, you have unlimited power without 3D mesh modeling.